# code debugging: 'take a list of ints between 0-9, return largest number divisible by 3'

Tags: python-2.7, list, debugging, combinations, python-itertools

I'm trying to understand what is wrong with my current solution.
The problem is as follows:

using python 2.7.6"

You have `L`, a list containing some digits (0 to 9). Write a function `answer(L)` which finds the largest number that can be made from some or all of these digits and is divisible by 3. if it is not possible to make such a number, return 0 as the answer. `L` will contain anywhere from 1 to 9 digits. The same digit may appear multiple times in the list, but each element in the list may only be used once.

```
input: (int list) l = [3, 1, 4, 1]
output: (int) 4311
input (int list) l = [3 ,1 ,4 ,1 ,5, 9]
output: (int) = 94311
```

This is my code to tackle the problem:

```
import itertools

def answer(l):
    '#remove the zeros to speed combinatorial analysis:'
    zero_count = l.count(0)
    for i in range(l.count(0)):
        l.pop(l.index(0))

   ' # to check if a number is divisible by three, check if the sum '
   ' # of the individual integers that make up the number is divisible '
   ' # by three. (e.g.  431:  4+3+1 = 8,  8 % 3 != 0,  thus 431 % 3 != 0)'
    b = len(l)
    while b > 0:
        combo = itertools.combinations(l, b)
        for thing in combo:

            '# if number is divisible by 3, reverse sort it and tack on zeros left behind' 

            if sum(thing) % 3 == 0:
                thing = sorted(thing, reverse = True)
                max_div_3 = ''
                for digit in thing:
                    max_div_3 += str(digit)
                max_div_3 += '0'* zero_count
                return int(max_div_3)
        b -= 1

    return int(0)
```

I have tested this assignment many times in my own sandbox and it always works.
However when I have submitted it against my instructor, I end up always failing 1 case.. with no explanation of why. I cannot interrogate the instructor's tests, they are blindly pitched against the code.

Does anyone have an idea of a condition under which my code fails to either return the largest integer divisible by 3 or, if none exists, 0?
The list always has at least one number in it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was with the order of itertools.combinations(l, b)
and sorted(thing, reverse = True). The original code was finding the first match of n%3 == 0 but not necessarily the largest match. Performing sort BEFORE itertools.combinations allowed itertools to find the largest n%3 == 0.

Comment: Thank God for this... All my test cases were passing because I was also taking sorting after itertools. Learned Something New. Thanks @MBS